# Colored background on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar that's 30px high. How can I get the background color of the menu item link to fill the entire height of the nav bar on hover? My concern is if I use padding top/bottom if the screen is sized or zoom it will not display properly.

HTML

```
<nav>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `a` element to the full height and use the hover element as you have;

```
nav ul li a {
    height: 30px; /* or 100% */
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Sweet! Didn't even know you can specify height property in 'a'. Thanks!

Comment: You can't unless it's an `inline-block` element (or `block`, but you don't want that here). An `a` is an `inline` element by default, hence setting the display type.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following:

```
nav ul li a {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Remove `height` from `nav`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to color the whole nav? Here it is.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

nav:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</nav>
```